# bash pass pairs of argument in case statement

Tags: bash, loops, unix, hadoop, case

I am trying to find an efficient way to loop an action based on a pair of arguments e.g. (a, b, c, d, e, f....etc ) and (1,2,3,4,5,..... etc). The script should loop through a given folder of files, look for matching filenames and take action accordingly. However, the $dir1,$dir2,$dir3...etc has no fixed naming pattern based on filename that I can generate dynamically for each loop. I have a predefined list of filename string, and their corresponding hdfs folder locations.

Can someone help suggest a better way so that I can do the same operation in a loop instead of rewriting the common action for each case?

below is a sample pseudo code snippet.
sample input files and their corresponding directories:

```
BATMAN_JOKER_SUPERMAN.txt >>>  $dir1  
BATMAN_HARLEYQUIN_SUPERMAN.txt >>> $dir2  
BATMAN_DEADSHOT_SUPERMAN.txt>>> $dir3
```

assuming all variables are declared

```
for filename in $(ls $home_dir| grep $ProcessDate | grep global)  
do 
    fname=$(sed 's|`\(.*BATMAN_ *\)\(.*\)\( *_SUPERMAN.*\)$|\2|g' <<< $filename)  
    case "$fname" in  
    JOKER) 
    #lots of actions that are common to each file  
    hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $filename $dir1  
    ;;  
    HARLEYQUIN)  
    #lots of actions that are common to each file  
    hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $filename $dir2  
    ;;  
    DEADSHOT)  
    #lots of actions that are common to each file  
    hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $filename $dir3  
    ;;  
esac  
done;
```

Comment: Use an associative array mapping filename to directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
case "$fname" in
  *JOKER*)
    ...
  ;;
  *HARLEYQUIN*)
    ...
  ;;
  *DEADSHOT*)
    ...
  ;;
esac
```